# Retrieving multiple AWS secrets manager in 1 call

Tags: mule, aws-secrets-manager

I have more than 3 secrets stored in aws secret manager and would like to retrieve 2 secrets at a time for my application. A call to getSecretValue() can return the result for only 1 secret at a time. Would you please suggest how one can retrieve multiple secrets from aws secret manager with a single function call?

Comment: What's your hesitation to making multiple getsecretvalue calls?

Comment: @committedandroider let's say I have 100+ secrets in my application. And I want to fetch all the values of those secrets when application is being initialized. Then 100+ api calls would be time consuming task I guess.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: Secrets Manager now supports [BatchGetSecretValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_BatchGetSecretValue.html)

<s>It is not currently possible to do batch calls with Secrets Manager</s>. However, if you store your secrets in JSON format, you could store multiple key/value pairs in one secret.

I would not recommend doing this, however, unless these secrets are strongly related. For example, a set of secrets needed by a single application. Even then, you should avoid this if possible. Combining secrets causes problems if you try to automate rotation, and becomes a problem when you need to split up an application and the permissions/secrets that go along with them.

Comment: Is this still not possible to this day?

Comment: Secrets Manager does not support batch operations but it does support [high call rates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_limits.html) and provides [caching libraries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets.html) for many languages.